# Old Maven Dependency has Broken My Build

Tags: maven, grails, groovy

I downloaded the following [library](https://github.com/berngp/httpbuilder/tree/branch/add/MultiPart-Form), navigated to its directory, and entered `mvn install`.

Since then, my Grails project in STS will not build:

> General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download
>   failed: org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;1.7.11!groovy.jar]

I think I accidentally added a dependency on the old groovy 1.7.11. How can I remove the library and fix my Grails project?

Comment: Maven usually installs the jar files in a directory called `.m2` (usually in your home directory). Go into that directory and find the files installed by MultiPart-Form and delete them.

Comment: Are you building your grails project using Maven too?

Comment: I'm using a new install of STS 3.1 - not sure if that builds with Maven. I have deleted the repository in ~/.m2 and I do still have the error about downloading groovy 1.7.11

Comment: Here's a clue - I created a new/empty Grails project in STS and it fails to compile with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This project uses the old (v 1.x) version of groovy-eclipse. Here's how to fix:

1. delete .project and .classpath (outside of eclipse)
2. install m2e v1.2 into your eclipse
3. install the groovy-eclipse m2e configurator
4. import project using the "Import existing maven project wizard"
5. Rejoice